# Bulk Update/Insert in Mongodb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How do I bulk update/insert (bulk upsert) in Mongo with C#.

I am updating a couple fields if the data has changed and inserting if it does not exist.  The source of the data also does not provide me with unique identifiers and I have to generate my own based on combining several fields.

**Update:**

Using Kirk's help from the linked post I came up with this solution which seemed to work and ran 150 data items in 20 ms to 140ms.

```
 public async Task<List<ChallengeData<T>>> BulkUpsertChallengeData<T>(string challengeIdentifier,
        List<ChallengeData<T>> challengeDatas)
    {

        var updateStatements = new List<UpdateOneModel<ChallengeData<T>>>();
        foreach (var challengeData in challengeDatas)
        {
            var updateStatement = new UpdateOneModel<ChallengeData<T>>(
                Builders<ChallengeData<T>>.Filter.Where(p =>
                    p.ChallengeDataIdentifier == challengeData.ChallengeDataIdentifier),
                Builders<ChallengeData<T>>.Update
                    .Set(p => p.CompanyIdentifier, challengeData.CompanyIdentifier)
                    .Set(p => p.ChallengeDataIdentifier, challengeData.ChallengeDataIdentifier)
                    .Set(p => p.ChallengeDataProviderType, challengeData.ChallengeDataProviderType)
                    .Set(p => p.DataType, challengeData.DataType)
                    .Set(p => p.DateForData, challengeData.DateForData)
                    .Set(p => p.Recipient, challengeData.Recipient)
                    .Set(p => p.Tags, challengeData.Tags)
                    .Set(p => p.Value, challengeData.Value)
                    .SetOnInsert(p => p.DateCreated, challengeData.DateCreated)
                    .Set(p => p.DateUpdated, challengeData.DateUpdated)
            ) {IsUpsert = true};

            updateStatements.Add(updateStatement);

        }

       await Db.GetChallengeCollection<ChallengeData<T>>(challengeIdentifier).BulkWriteAsync(updateStatements);
        return challengeDatas;
    }
```

Db.GetChallengeCollection is a custom extension which basically does a Db.GetCollection("name")

Comment: It looks like you might've posted this question twice as different users, but on the off-chance this is not the case, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104577/is-a-mongodb-bulk-upsert-possible-c-sharp-driver.

Comment: This was a coworker who apparently also turned to stackoverflow for the answer on my behalf.  Thanks!