# Is a MongoDB bulk upsert possible? C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'd like to do a bulk upsert in Mongo. Basically I'm getting a list of objects from a vendor, but I don't know which ones I've gotten before (and need to be updated) vs which ones are new. One by one I could do an upsert, but UpdateMany doesn't work with upsert options.

So I've resorted to selecting the documents, updating in C#, and doing a bulk insert.

```
    public async Task BulkUpsertData(List<MyObject> newUpsertDatas)
    {
        var usernames = newUpsertDatas.Select(p => p.Username);
        var filter = Builders<MyObject>.Filter.In(p => p.Username, usernames);

        //Find all records that are in the list of newUpsertDatas (these need to be updated)
        var collection = Db.GetCollection<MyObject>("MyCollection");
        var existingDatas = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

        //loop through all of the new data, 
        foreach (var newUpsertData in newUpsertDatas)
        {
            //and find the matching existing data
            var existingData = existingDatas.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == newUpsertData.Id);
            //If there is existing data, preserve the date created (there are other fields I preserve)
            if (existingData == null)
            {
                newUpsertData.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                newUpsertData.Id = existingData.Id;
                newUpsertData.DateCreated = existingData.DateCreated;
            }
        }

        await collection.DeleteManyAsync(filter);
        await collection.InsertManyAsync(newUpsertDatas);
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT:

I did some speed tests.

In preparation I inserted 100,000 records of a pretty simple object. Then I upserted 200,000 records into the collection.

Method 1 is as outlined in the question. SelectMany, update in code, DeleteMany, InsertMany. This took approximately 5 seconds.

Method 2 was making a list of UpdateOneModel with Upsert = true and then doing one BulkWriteAsync. This was super slow. I could see the count in the mongo collection increasing so I know it was working. But after about 5 minutes it had only climbed to 107,000 so I canceled it.

I'm still interested if anyone else has a potential solution

Answer (score 7):

Given that you've said you *could* do a one-by-one upsert, you can achieve what you want with [`BulkWriteAsync`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_BulkWriteAsync.htm). This allows you to create one or more instances of the abstract [`WriteModel`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_WriteModel_1.htm), which in your case would be instances of [`UpdateOneModel`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateOneModel_1.htm).

In order to achieve this, you could do something like the following:

```
var listOfUpdateModels = new List<UpdateOneModel<T>>();

// ...

var updateOneModel = new UpdateOneModel<T>(
    Builders<T>.Filter. /* etc. */,
    Builders<T>.Update. /* etc. */)
{
    IsUpsert = true;
};

listOfUpdateModels.Add(updateOneModel);

// ...

await mongoCollection.BulkWriteAsync(listOfUpdateModels);
```

The key to all of this is the [`IsUpsert`](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateOneModel_1_IsUpsert.htm) property on `UpdateOneModel`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  How efficient is this with potentially 600,000 rows of data?

Comment: According to another answer, this might not be something you need to worry about as the driver takes care of splitting it into batches for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24257439/2630078. Having said that, you could take control of this by creating your own batches and calling `BulkWriteAsync` multiple times, etc.

Comment: Sorry for the super slow reply. I've been a little busy but wanted to run a test on the different solutions. I found that running a BulkWriteAsync is not an option for me. Thank you for the answer though!